# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "bar"

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

Trying to create this example table structure in Postgres 9.1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    name        VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
    pkey        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    foo_fk      VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(name), 
    name        VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (foo_fk,name)
);

CREATE TABLE baz(   
    pkey        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bar_fk      VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL REFERENCES bar(name),
    name        VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Running the above code produces an error, which does not make sense to me:

> ```
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "foo_pkey" for table "foo"
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "bar_pkey_seq" for serial column "bar.pkey"
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "bar_pkey" for table "bar"
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will create implicit index "bar_foo_fk_name_key" for table "bar"
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "baz_pkey_seq" for serial column "baz.pkey"
> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "baz_pkey" for table "baz"
> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "bar"
> ```

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "bar"
SQL state: 42830
```

Can anyone explain why this error arises?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

It's because the `name` column on the `bar` table does not have the *UNIQUE* constraint.

So imagine you have 2 rows on the `bar` table that contain the name `'ams'` and you insert a row on `baz` with `'ams'` on `bar_fk`, which row on `bar` would it be referring since there are two rows matching?

Comment: Both of them maybe? isn't that how one-to-many relation work?

Comment: @shamaseen that would make it many-to-many as there could be multiple `baz`s. Foreign key is only supposed to be used as one-to-many

Comment: @Hritik I might be having a stupid moment, but isn't it a many-to-one relationship as you can have many pointers as long as they each only point to one value (row)?

Comment: Got the error 'there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"' in Supabase trying to add a foreign key constraint. Hadn't made users.id unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 138):

In postgresql all foreign keys must reference a **unique key** in the parent table, so in your `bar` table you must have a `unique (name)` index.

See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK and specifically:

> Finally, we should mention that **a foreign key must reference columns
>   that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: why isn't the declared PK considered as a unique constraint ?  it's not like you can have a nonunique PK...

Comment: It must be unique on the table it "points to", because if it is not, the database engine will have no way to know which row you are actually referring to.

Comment: Composite keys? @amphibient

Comment: I think having a unique key on the referenced column on parent table is not required in postgresql only but also it other RDBMSs too like oracle, sql server etc.

Comment: Maybe, but certainly not all of them, for example MySQL requires just a simple index, which may be non unique

Comment: Note that the answer is true also for composite foreign keys, where a composite unique constraint or primary key is required on the parent table.

Comment: @CharmingRobot 
"it can be said that the PRIMARY KEY of a table is a combination of NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraint."

https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/primary-key-constraint.php

Comment: @amphibient Because the `UNIQUE` constraint is required on the target column(s). The FK targets `bar.name`, but the PK is on `bar.id`.

Answer (score 16):

You should have name column as a unique constraint. here is a 3 lines of code to change your issues

1. First find out the primary key constraints by typing this code

   ```
   \d table_name
   ```

   you are shown like this at bottom `"some_constraint" PRIMARY KEY, btree (column)`
2. Drop the constraint:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT some_constraint
   ```
3. Add a new primary key column with existing one:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT some_constraint PRIMARY KEY(COLUMN_NAME1,COLUMN_NAME2);
   ```

That's All.

Answer (score 13):

when you do `UNIQUE` as a table level constraint as you have done then what your defining is a bit like a composite primary key see [ddl constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html), here is an extract

> This specifies that the *combination* of values in the indicated columns is unique across the whole table, though any one of the columns need not be (and ordinarily isn't) unique.

this means that either field could possibly have a non unique value provided the **combination** is unique and this does not match your foreign key constraint.

most likely you want the constraint to be at column level. so rather then define them as table level constraints, 'append' `UNIQUE` to the end of the column definition like `name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE` or specify indivdual table level constraints for each field.

Comment: Column level constraint in my situation will not work I really should be defining a compound primary key, but I backed away from it because mapping it to JPA its a bit of a pain :)