# Why am I getting "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table..." Error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

According to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966420/what-is-causing-error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-ref), *there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "..."* is an error you get when you make a foreign key reference call to a column which is not unique. But why am I getting this error here?

```
postgres=# create database example;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# \c example
You are now connected to database "masterdb" as user "postgres".

masterdb=# create table foo(
id bigserial
);
CREATE TABLE

masterdb=# create table bar (
id bigserial,
foo_fid bigint not null references foo (id)
);
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "foo"
```

Comment: The fk must reference a key, but the foo column id is not a key.

Comment: @jarlh I thought `BIGSERIAL` implied `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: "_It is important to note that the SERIAL does not implicitly create an index on the column or make the column as the primary key column._" https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/

Comment: `BIGSERIAL` is just a psuedo-type [serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) that generates numbers from a sequence. You need to specify `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` if you want that column to be used by a `FOREIGN KEY`. Same applies to `GENERATED AS IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table has to have unique index on the referenced column:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: More commonly, it would be the primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Most often, but not always. Sometimes you need another unique index besides your primary key.