# PostgreSQL - delete all post reactions when deleting a post?

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql

I'm having trouble delete post having reactions (likes) because of the foreign key associating the `post.id` with the `post_reaction.post_id`.

I'd like to create a foreign key with CASCADE on delete, but because a post can have many post_reactions, I get a an error: `no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "post_reactions"`

I shouldn't think I'd have to delete everything individually on the client side, should I? i.e. delete all the post_reactions first, then the post?

```
  const handleDeletePost = () => {
    if (postImageRelayId) {
      ImageDeleteMutation(postImageRelayId); // if there is an image, delete it
    }
    if (postReactions.length) {
      PostReactionDeleteMutation(postReactions); // if there are reactions, delete all of them
    }
    PostDeleteMutation(post.id, currentPerson); // delete post itself
  };
```

The image table has a post_id column with an fkey to post.id

The post_reactions table has a post_id column also with an fkey to the post.id

I'd like to simply delete the post from the posts table and postgres CASCADE delete any reaction and / or image having that post_id, but, I'm unable to create a foreign key on the post table referencing **post_reactions.post_id**.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it clear what workflow you want during deletion.

Comment: You need to have post.id marked as the PRIMARY KEY for it to work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966420/what-is-causing-error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-ref

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is causing ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966420/what-is-causing-error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-ref)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Kind thanks. I added my current delete function which calls three mutations. I'm not sure what specific data would help.

Comment: @Jim I have a pkey on the post table (id).

Comment: @jim I saw that one. I need to learn more about keys and constraints because I'm stabbing in the dark as to what is possible and what is smart.

Comment: bad arg in `PostReactionDeleteMutation(postReactions)` ? test mutations in playground BEFORE coding!

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key has to point from `post_reactions` to `posts`, not the other way around, as your error message suggests you tried to do.

Comment: That's how it is. And if I try to delete a post without first deleting reactions which have that fkey relation to it, the delete fails. I was hoping there was a way to tell postgres to delete any rows in foreign tables which have an fkey pointing to the post's id.

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood CASCADE. I thought CASCADE needed to be on the post table not the post_reactions table.

I added it to the post_reactions_post_id fkey and it works now.

```
ALTER TABLE wuddit.post_reactions
    ADD CONSTRAINT post_reactions_post_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
    REFERENCES wuddit.post (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
    ON DELETE CASCADE; // this
```