# Query tool response pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY rental ADD CONSTRAINT rental_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "customer"

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY customer ADD CONSTRAINT customer_store_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(store_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE ONLY film ADD CONSTRAINT film_language_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES language(language_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE ONLY inventory ADD CONSTRAINT inventory_store_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(store_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "inventory" violates foreign key constraint

I get these messages when i use the query tool for a sql query of over 1300 lines of code. I'm still learning so any pointers will be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966420/what-is-causing-error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-ref